# How do i move text to the center of a vertical axis

Tags: html, css

I wrote below code.

```
<ul class="collection">
  <img src="/images/remove.png" class="remove">
  <a href="hogehoge">AAAAAAAA</a>
</ul>
```

I want to move 'a' tag to center of vertical axis. But it becomes like below image.[image]

What should I do?

Comment: I did not write css of that tags. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` and `text-align:middle`

```css
.collection img,
.collection a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul class="collection">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-25-25-2.jpg" class="remove" />
  <a href="hogehoge">AAAAAAAA</a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks you! I was saved.